# How to 'free' memory allocated to a variable in shell

Tags: shell, memory, free, local-variables

```
function mem(){
local token
return $token
}

obj=$(ls)                      #list of object name
objstr=($obj)                  #array[i] whose ith element is object name
objno=$(echo "$obj" | wc -w)   #the number of object name

for i in $(seq 0 $(($objno-1)))
do
    objID=${objstr[$i]}    #object name
    IDlen=${#objID}        #length of object name
    for j in $(seq 0 $(($IDlen-1)))
    do
        subID=${objID:$j:1}        #charater in the name
        token=$(mem)               #allocate local variable returned
        token[0]+=$subID           #concatenate characters
    done
```

I want to define a variable in which I can store an objects name.
(in a way that I can access each characters in the name)
But the most important thing is that it has to be disposable.
I want to 'free' the memory allocated to the variable before going on with another object name to minimize overhead.
So I defined a function, mem() which would return local variable.
If I initialize token[0] to the returned variable each time before I use it,
what happens to the memory previously allocated to the variable? Is it 'free'ed as intended?

Comment: `return` takes a number.

Comment: `$token` isn't a number. It's empty, so `return $token` is just `return`. A bare `return` uses the exit status of the last command executed in the function. There isn't one, so my guess is that `mem` is equivalent to `function mem() { return 0; }`.

Comment: The *$IDlen* variable is used, but isn't defined in the code above.

Comment: @melpomene oh i see. either wouldnt be a problem i checked the code above and works fine

Comment: @agc thanks corrected

Comment: thanks for the comments but as mentioned in the question what i really wanna know is how to free the memory and whether my code frees the memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't free memory in the shell; there are no explicit ways to free such things as the storage for variables. That said, you could try

- using local variables if your shell supports them; they may get freed when they go out of scope
- `unset NAME` once you're done with `NAME`

Note that just like in C, this doesn't guarantee the memory is returned to the OS.

But then, **why do you worry about memory for shell variables** in the first place? What is your *actual* problem? If memory use and management is a constraint, maybe the shell is the wrong tool?

Comment: I need to change all objects in a given directory including the ones in its subdirectory. I need to use recursive function and i figured if i don't free the memory then i might get some errors when i try to apply this script to large number of files

Comment: I tried local variable, it works. but according to:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html,
local variable declared in a function is also visible to functions called by the parent function. which means that if i use local variable in the recursive function, it is highly likely to remain in the memory until all the recursive children it called end.

Comment: unset command - It unsets a shell variable, removing it from memory and the shell's exported environment. -wikipedia thanks a lot! –

Comment: How many are *a large number of files*`? Why do you need recursion in the shell script? How deep is the expected recursion? This very much looks like a problem that could be solved iteratively.

Comment: Well im not sure Its a school assignment they didnt tell me how big the test sample would be. How would you solve this iteratively

Comment: oh i made a mistake on my first comment the assignments requirement was to change the name of all the objects not the objects themselves I need to change case of the names

Comment: Your objects seem to be file names. To modify filenames (=rename them) you would use `find .  -type f | while read name; do mv "$name" "$(some transformation of $name)"; done`. There are tools in the Unix toolbox that do the recursion. Use them, don't reinvent them. You are totally overthinking this.